# How is this valid xml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm calling a webservice that returns an XML document. When I call it it returns the following:

```
    resultsetrecordtxnref1013101155943920/txnrefchannelvisa/channelamount1000.00/amountpayment_date4/11/2013 3:59:43 PM/payment_datepayment_statussuccessful/payment_statusfield_valuesfield_valuesfieldnamesTest Test/namesacct_descFalse/acct_descacct_desc_order0/acct_desc_orderhiddenFalse/hiddendefaultvalue /xpath_field0/xpath_field/fieldfieldamount1000.00/amountacct_descFalse/acct_descacct_desc_order0/acct_desc_orderhiddenFalse/hiddendefaultvalue /xpath_field0/xpath_field/fieldfieldcurrencyNGN/currencyacct_descFalse/acct_descacct_desc_order0/acct_desc_orderhiddenFalse/hiddendefaultvalue /xpath_field0/xpath_field/fieldfieldemail_addresstest/email_addressacct_descFalse/acct_descacct_desc_order0/acct_desc_orderhiddenFalse/hiddendefaultvalue /xpath_field0/xpath_field/fieldfieldphone_number+2348031155249/phone_numberacct_descFalse/acct_descacct_desc_order0/acct_desc_orderhiddenFalse/hiddendefaultvalue /xpath_field0/xpath_field/fieldfieldmerch_txnref0/merch_txnrefacct_descFalse/acct_descacct_desc_order0/acct_desc_orderhiddenFalse/hiddendefaultvalue /xpath_field0/xpath_field/field/field_values/field_valuespayment_status_descriptionTransaction Successful - Approved/payment_status_description/record/resultset
```

Is this valid XML because when I use `simplexml_load_string` it works on my local server which runs PHP 5.4 but not on my testing server which uses PHP 5.3

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The page source also doesn't have the tags. 
Also how do I change the content type.

Comment: With `header()`, of course. But I was referring to the remote webserver :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Lol.. sorry I'm kind of flustered by this problem. If the webservice is returning the wrong content type, why would it work on my local machine and not on my staging server. 
Shouldn't it fail on both?

Comment: SimpleXML doesn't use Content-Type. It expects XML so it assumes XML. It was an attempt to explain why your browser (which *should* use Content-Type) failed to recognise it as XML. If you say that's your actual input we'll have to trust you but it's very strange that SimpleXML accepts that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of your browser parsing the XML and ignoring all the tags.  Try viewing the page source or using a browser that can handle XML.

Comment: Most likely, the web server returns the XML with `Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: I have checked the source and it doesn't have the tags either.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason setting turning on the `php_openssl.dll` fixed the problem. Not sure why ... but google says so

Comment: This would be an issue of not enough info in your question.  Openssl is required to make a connection to a HTTPS resource, so I bet that your address starts with https://